# rbuf reading data from file, but unable to transfer it to array

Tags: c, system-calls

So I've got a compiled readNumbers function that's supposed to read numbers from an input file and an rbuf buffer that reads bits of the file to be transferred to an array. However, when I give it an input, say,
12 3 5 6 7 34 11,
it's only reading one character from the file before it sets everything else to 0 and finishes.

```
int readNumbers(int **array, char* fname) {

    char *errmsg = "Failed to open input file!\n";
    char rbuf[16];
    int numberRead = 0, numberAllocated = 2, fd;
    int temp = 0, i = 0;
    int nRead = 0, negative = 1;
    int newNumber = 0;

    *array = (int *)malloc(numberAllocated * sizeof(int));

    fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (fd == -1){

        write(2, errmsg, 31);
        return (-1);
    }

    while ((nRead = read(fd, rbuf, 16)!=0)){
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            printf("%d, ", rbuf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < nRead; i++){
            printf("A, %d\n", nRead);
            if (numberRead == numberAllocated){
                numberAllocated *= 2;
                *array = (int *)realloc(*array, numberAllocated * sizeof(int));
            }

            if (rbuf[i] == '-'){
                negative = (-1);
            }
            else if (isdigit(rbuf[i])){
                printf("B");
                if (newNumber == 0){
                    printf("C\n");
                    temp = rbuf[i] - '0';
                    printf("%d\n", temp);
                    newNumber = 1;
                }
                else{
                    printf("D");
                    temp *= 10;
                    temp += (rbuf[i] - '0');
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("E");
                if (newNumber == 1){
                    temp *= negative;
                    *array[i] = temp;
                    negative = 1;
                    temp = 0;
                    newNumber = 0;
                    numberRead ++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            rbuf[i] = '\0';
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    return numberRead;
}
```

Any ideas? It feels like the issue has something to do with `read()` and `nRead`, but I can't figure out what it is.

The current output is:
    49, 50, 32, 51, 10, 53, 32, 54, 32, 55, 10, 51, 52, 32, 49, 49;
    A, 1;
    BC;
    1;

Comment: I know the output is working correctly, but only because I'm intentionally pulling out exactly 16 bytes. The idea is that nRead keeps track of exactly how many are read based on read(), so when it reaches the end of the program and there happens to be 7 bytes left, it doesn't print out garbage.  The *array[numberRead] part is right though.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution to this one, as it turns out.

```
while ((nRead = read(fd, rbuf, 16)!=0)){
```

So if you look closely, you'd see that something was wrong with the parentheses here. The correct format would be something like this:

```
while ((nRead = read(fd, rbuf, 16))!=0){
```

So yeah. Basically it was checking to see if the actual number of characters read wasn't zero before assigning that truth value to the variable meant to hold the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize i counter to `0` before this part

```
if (rbuf[i] == '-'){
    negative = (-1);
  }
  else if (isdigit(rbuf[i])){
    printf("B");
    if (newNumber == 0){
      printf("C\n");
      temp = rbuf[i] - '0';
      printf("%d\n", temp);
      newNumber = 1;
    } 
    else{
      printf("D");
      temp *= 10;
      temp += (rbuf[i] - '0');
    }
  }
  else{
    printf("E");
    if (newNumber == 1){
      temp *= negative;
      *array[i] = temp;
      negative = 1;
      temp = 0;
      newNumber = 0;
      numberRead ++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is 0 though. It starts at 0 and gets refreshed every time rbuf picks up a new 16 bytes.